# How do you open up a Comkia MobiMe G3?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I can't open it to replace the hard drive inside. I can take off the cover but I cannot get the thing inside out.

Answer (score 1):

the 2 black covers on top AND on the bottom can be unscrewed and be removed... the electronics board is not supposed to be removed from the white plastic part!